# Maximal torus and the structure of complex flag manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Consider the compact Lie group $G=T\cdot S$ with finite intersection $I:=T\cap S$,  where $T$ is the central torus and $S$ the maximal semisimple subgroup. Now, $S/I\cong G/T$ has the structure of a complex flag manifold.

Since $S/I$ is a Lie group, Does it mean that it has the structure of a  complex Lie group? I was thinking in the case where the intersection is finite then if $S$ is complex Lie group then it is abelian since it is compact!

So if $S/I$ is not a complex Lie group, what its complexification?

Comment: It is both a complex manifold and a Lie group, but as you observe $S$ is usually rather nonabelian, so the multiplication map is not holomorphic. I don't know the answer to your second question.

Comment: So if $H $ is a closed subgroup of $S $ such that $(S/I)/H$ is compact.  Is $(S/I)/H$ also a complex flag manifold?

Comment: I would guess you can find odd-dimensional $H$, which means no (by a dimension-count).

Comment: Yes you right.  But I was trying to understand  $S/I $-orbits. Do you think they are complex manifolds?

Comment: I am far from expert, which is why I won't write any of this as an answer. But my guess is that unless you specifically have some magic like the diffeomorphism to $G^\Bbb C/B$ as in the generalized flag variety case, there will probably be counterexamples. Also, I would guess $I$ is rarely a normal subgroup of $S$.

Comment: $I $ is normal since it is central.  Isn't it? $I $ is zero dimensional anyway.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. I was thinking of the case $G/T$ for $T$ a maximal (not central) torus. But I am confused: let $G = SO(3)$; then its center is trivial and $G$ is simple. But $G$ is not a complex manifold. So I am not sure what $G$ your question applies to.

Comment: Sorry.  I meant if the maximal torus is central.

Comment: I think that a compact connected Lie group with maximal torus central is necessarily a torus itself. This is because the Lie algebra of a compact Lie group is reductive (direct sum of abelian and semisimple); semisimple Lie algebras have trivial center, so the center is the abelian summand. However a semisimple lie algebra of positive dimension does still have nontrivial maximal abelian subalgebra, and hence the maximal torus is of strictly larger dimension than the center as long as the semisimple part is nontrivial. So the Lie algebra is abelian, and the Lie group is a torus.